# Set start date and expiration date for Rails cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

How do I set a Rails cookie to start and/or expire at a certain date?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Excerpts from [Rails 5 documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html):

> Cookies are read and written through ActionController#cookies.
>
> The cookies being read are the ones received along with the request, the cookies being written will be sent out with the response. Reading a cookie does not get the cookie object itself back, just the value it holds.
>
> Examples of writing:
>
> ```
> # Sets a simple session cookie.
> # This cookie will be deleted when the user's browser is closed.
> cookies[:user_name] = "david"
>
> # Sets a cookie that expires in 1 hour.
> cookies[:login] = { value: "XJ-122", expires: 1.hour }
>
> # Sets a cookie that expires at a specific time.
> cookies[:login] = { value: "XJ-122", expires: Time.utc(2020, 10, 15, 5) }
>
> # Sets a "permanent" cookie (which expires in 20 years from now).
> cookies.permanent[:login] = "XJ-122"
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The option symbols for setting cookies are:
>
> - `:expires` - The time at which this cookie expires, as a Time or ActiveSupport::Duration object.
>
> [...]

Comment: This is all in the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

Comment: @Senthil, If you are getting something from another article (in this case 'as is' from rails docs), Please give a reference to the origin.

Comment: also :expires option should be a Time instance. 

`cookies[:login] = { value: "JX-122", expires: 3.months }`
would raise error.

but this won't.
`cookies[:login] = { value: "JX-122", expires: 3.months.from_now }`

see for details https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/864#issuecomment-104706555

Answer (score 21):

your question might be related to this question:
[How to I dynamically set the expiry time for a cookie-based session in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249797/how-to-i-dynamically-set-the-expiry-time-for-a-cookie-based-session-in-rails)

one of the comments points to [Deprecating SlideSessions](http://squarewheel.pl/posts/3):

> "..If you need to set expiration period
>   for sessions through all controllers
>   in your application, simply add the
>   following option to your
>   config/intializers/session_store.rb
>   file:
>
> ```
> :expire_after => 60.minutes
> ```
>
> If you need to set different
>   expiration time in different
>   controllers or actions, use the
>   following code in action or some
>   before_filter:
>
> ```
> request.session_options = request.session_options.dup
> request.session_options[:expire_after]= 5.minutes
> request.session_options.freeze
> ```
>
> Duplication of the hash is needed only
>   because it is already frozen at that
>   point, even though modification of at
>   least :expire_after is possible and
>   works flawlessly..."

I hope that helps. :)

Comment: Can this be done for ActiveRecord session store as well?

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that as of right now it is impossible to set a start time for a cookie. A cookie set is always active immediately.