# setting Facebook Connect cookie expiration when using Rails/OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, facebook, omniauth

I have a Rails 3 app that authenticates users using  (v0.2.6).  In OmniAuth, I am only using Facebook as the authentication provider.

My omniauth.rb file looks like this...

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    key = 'a6h456kh78gnjh4kjh7'      # not my real API key
    secret = 'kjh45kj56odf987yjkh3'  # not my real secret either
    provider :facebook, key, secret
end
```

This works, but the Facebook cookie expiration seems to be set as "session".  Is there a way to have the Facebook cookie expiration last for a longer period of time?  Ideally I'd like to set it for a year.

Answer (score 0):

Set a permanent cookie using:

```
cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
```

Comment: How do you do that using omniauth?

Comment: Add it into your sessions controller. See how in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232174/rails-cookies-set-start-date-and-expire-date or take a read through http://m.onkey.org/signed-and-permanent-cookies-in-rails-3