# Ruby on Rails: How to set a Cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails cookies, set start date and expire date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232174/rails-cookies-set-start-date-and-expire-date)

How can I set a cookie in Rails? I need the equivalent of this PHP code:

```
<?php

setcookie("AFID", $_REQUEST['AFID'], time() + (60*60*24*365));
setcookie("SID", $_REQUEST['SID'], time() + (60*60*24*365));

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty straight forward:

```
cookies['AFID'] = {
  :value => request.env['AFID'],
  :expires => 1.year.from_now
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks in which page should i need to add this code. Please help

Comment: Wherever you want to set the cookie. Typically in the controller.

Comment: Hi i got following error. NoMethodError in HomeController#index

undefined method `request' for #<Hash:0x47045a0>..Please kelp

Comment: Try `request.env['AFID']` or just `env['AFID']`?

Comment: Michael is right, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: How can i add this  cookie code in the file /views/home/index.html.erb. Please help any procedure and also how can i test the cookie is site. Please help

Comment: I use this code in the file  /views/home/index.html.erb. cookies['AFID'] = {
  :value => request.env['AFID'],
  :expires => 1.year.from_now
}


cookies['SID'] = {
  :value => request.env['SID'],
  :expires => 1.year.from_now
}   It display in home page as {:value=>nil, :expires=>Thu, 04 Oct 2012 09:54:59 UTC +00:00, :path=>"/"} {:value=>nil, :expires=>Thu, 04 Oct 2012 09:54:59 UTC +00:00, :path=>"/"}