# Rails - How to delete Facebook Cookie from rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, facebook

I need to delete a facebook cookie that is stored to localhost when a user visits the sign in page, to ensure there isn't an issue FB Connecting.

The cookie is:

```
HOST: localhost
NAME: fbsr_113062422116500
PATH: /
SEND FOR: Any type
EXPIRES: At end of session
```

I tried deleting the cookie with:

```
<%= cookies[:fbsr_113062422116500].inspect %>
<BR>
<% cookies.delete(:fbsr_113062422116500) %>
```

But this returns nil and has no effect. Suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Only facebook can delete facebook cookies.

This is a security feature. Take a look at the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Alternatively, if you are trying to delete one of "your" cookies (perhaps storing some information about facebook), you can delete it by updating its expiration time.

[Rails cookies, set start date and expire date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232174/rails-cookies-set-start-date-and-expire-date) has some more info on deleting your own cookies in rails.

Comment: The site is localhost meaning it's my cookie correct? Not facebooks?

Comment: My guess is that you are indeed trying to delete your own cookie. But it is important to make the distinction. It may be the case that you don't need to delete the cookie at all, it depends on what you're trying to do. What kind of cookie store are you using? Did you try creating a simple action that just deletes the cookie,  instead of deleting inside of a partial?

Comment: Thanks I'd mark this as an answer if it showed how to actually delete the cookie. I'm trying what's above and it's still not working :) thx

Comment: Sounds good. If you provide a little more info I may be able to help more :)