# Check for existing Cookie with Rails 3 or Javascript / jQuery

Tags: jquery, cookies, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple login which starts off with a disabled login button unless the username and password are filled (this check is done by jQuery and removes the disabled attribute if filled).

The problem I am now having is checking to see if the fields are pre-filled by an existing cookie, if they are, then the pre-emptive disabled attribute should not be applied. I was thinking of doing this through Rails but perhaps it can also be done via Javascript / jQuery.

So the question in short could be: how do I check for a cookie in Rails 3.2.* or jQuery?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232174/rails-cookies-set-start-date-and-expire-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the controller you can just say `cookies["key"]` to get the value of something stored in a cookie.

Comment: This can also be done using jQuery through a plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery