# How to set rails session cookie expiration time to "session"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, session-timeout

I'm not very experienced with the parts of Rails that are not on the surface.

All I want is to have a session cookie that has the expiration set to `session` so it expires when the user leaves their browser or whatever. As a security measurement.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default the cookie is a session cookie.
You have complete control over the cookie by providing an options hash in `config/initializers/session_store.rb` . The options are the same as to `Rack::Session::Cookie`([**see docs**](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Session/Cookie)). So for example, for a specific expiration date you can provide `:expire_after` .

If you're using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), and **`rememberable`** strategy, then there's another cookie which can be used in order to retrieve the user.

Comment: expires_after doesn't seem to work, looks like it should be simply 'expires' with a date object. Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'Booya', expires: 7.days.from_now

Comment: @Roman can this be used for ActiveRecord session store as well?

Comment: on rails 5.2, the session cookie has `expires: Session` regardless of what I set `expire_after` to.

Answer (score 7):

You can configure it. Take a look at these links

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232216/1160106
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5861018/1160106