# Expire rails session variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Based on this answer: [Rails cookies, set start date and expire date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232174/rails-cookies-set-start-date-and-expire-date)

I attempted to do the same with a session variable:

```
session[:token] = { :value => @ticket.token, :expires => 1.minute.from_now }
```

However, the variable continues to be available after one minute. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried session.delete(:token)?

Comment: Yeah, but in this case I'm wanting to keep the token alive for a while. The user may need to access it for a short period of time, more than once.

Comment: Use a custom timestamp value in the session which you update each time the token is accessed or up until a certain point. If the token timestamp is out of date then act as if the token has expired.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you storing your session?

Check the below for guidance on choosing where to store the session, not all session stores implement expiry.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

[Setting session timeout in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860950/setting-session-timeout-in-rails-3)