# Cookies in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've known that session cookies will expire in default when we closed a browser. But I wanted to add function "auto logout" when inactive in 3 hours, I've tried expire_after: 3.hours in session_store but now when I close the browser, cookie still alive in 3 hours then reopen browser it still there.
How can I combine them together: close browser - logout and inactive in 3 hours - logout?

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232174/rails-cookies-set-start-date-and-expire-date

Answer (score 0):

You could try using javascript to both listen for the [browser close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event) and [expire the cookie](http://www.technofundo.com/tech/js/jscookies.html).