# Set cookie expiration time in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cookies, sinatra

I am using Ruby with Sinatra do develop a web application.
I have Ruby version 2.3.0, Sinatra 5.0.30

Following the suggestions from [Rails cookies, set start date and expire date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232174/rails-cookies-set-start-date-and-expire-date), I tried this:

```
@language = 'en-US'
response.set_cookie(:USER_LANGUAGE, :value => @language, :expires => 1.hour.from_now, :domain => '.example.com')
```

At first I thought it worked because the cookie set except the expiration time is still just only for the session. The error in my Apache error log says this: 
`NoMethodError - undefined method 'hour' for 1:Fixnum:`

Please note: none of these worked to resolve the problem (none of them could be properly found by the compiler)

1. `require 'active_support'`
2. `require 'active_support/all'`
3. `require 'activesupport'`

So, I tried this instead:

```
@language = 'en-US'
response.set_cookie(:USER_LANGUAGE, :value => @language, :expires => 30, :domain => '.example.com')
```

Just to see what would happen and nothing changed, it still only expires with the session.

How should I go about setting an expiration time for my cookies in Ruby with Sinatra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sinatra doesn't have the [`ActiveSupport`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html)  library which provides a helper for number-to-time, so `1.hour.from_now` doesn't works here.

You should use this:

```
class SinatraApp < Sinatra::Base

use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
                           :domain => 'foo.com',
                           :path => '/',
                           :expire_after => 2592000, # In seconds
                           :secret => 'some_secret'
```

And set a time in seconds. Because the Sinatra session comes from [`Rack::Session`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Session/Cookie).

<sub>[HOW TO ENABLE SESSIONS WITH SINATRA](http://www.getlaura.com/how-to-enable-sessions-with-sinatra)</sub>

Comment: Thank you. The link you provided to getlaura.com is the kind of document I have been searching for all day.