# How do I load a ruby variable via Ajax and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, watson-explorer

I am working in an application that uses Rails. I need to be able to set a variable for each user called language. Currently I do this through a ruby session variable that I setup in the controller, but when a user closes their browser I lose their language variable and they have to set it again every time they login. I need to attach this data to the user somehow. I have to use Ruby and Javascript on the front end and I can only make requests for data via Ruby.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var language=getCookie(“language”);
  //***HELP use ajax to set user language preference in ruby***

function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
</script>
 
<% use language variable here to request data in ruby %>
```

Comment: set an expiration date on the cookie when you set it?

Comment: My cookies have a high expiration. I don't show that code. My issue is how do I get the data from the user's browser into the ruby backend and still have it tied to the user. I need to set a ruby variable with ajax and javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ruby, by default, cookies only last till the session is closed. You can override that by just giving them an [expiration date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232174/rails-cookies-set-start-date-and-expire-date). Which means they'll last even if the user closes the browser, until they reach that expiration date, Just set it arbitrarily high and you'll be good to go.