# Session expiring on Safari Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, cookies

I´m using rails 3.2.13 and i wanted to change the active_record session store to 24 hours so i set:

```
Uauauanamobile::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :expire_after => 24.hours
```

In config/initializers/session_store.rb but if i inspect my iPhone Safari's cookies i don't see the _session_id cookie and of course isnt there (ominauth fails).
Is this a bug?

I need to set the expiry time because if i use my site as a web app (using the Add to home screen iOS feature) otherwise the app never saves the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another question, but as a reference i´ll copy it (the other question is phrased towards another problem but the solution is the same)

This is for rails 3.x so the solution is to set the expire time in every request like this:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

      after_filter :short_session

      ...

      def short_session
        request.session_options = request.session_options.dup
        request.session_options[:expire_after] = 1.minute
        request.session_options.freeze
      end
```

This is the original answer where this code was taken.

[How to I dynamically set the expiry time for a cookie-based session in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249797/how-to-i-dynamically-set-the-expiry-time-for-a-cookie-based-session-in-rails/14544511#14544511)

And yes this fixes the issue with webapp mode in iOS not saving the session.